# Help me write a binary search for boundary values (extracting sub lists)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, search, binary

Let's say I have an array of lots of values (C++ syntax, sorry):

```
vector<double> x(100000);
```

This array is sorted such that `x[n] > x[n-1]`.

I would like a function to retrieve an array of all values in the range [a, b] (that's inclusive). Some interface like:

```
void subarray(const double a, const double b, vector<double> &sub) {
    ...
}
```

When this function completes, `sub` will contain the `n` values that fell in the range [a, b].

Of course a linear search is easy:

```
void subarray(const double a, const double b, vector<double> &sub) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        if (a <= data[i] && data[i] <= b) {
            sub.push_back(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, because `data` is sorted, I should be able to do this much faster using a binary search. Who wants to take a stab at it? Any language is permitted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking is a bit confusing regarding the the exact range properties and the types.  However, you can tweak the following C++ code to suit your needs.  The basic intuition is to use lower_bound and upper_bound to find the positions in the array that delineate the range you're looking for.

```
void subarray(const double a, const double b, vector <double> &sub, vector <int> pn) {
    vector <int>::const_iterator begin, end;
    begin = lower_bound(pn.begin(), pn.end(), a);
    end = upper_bound(pn.begin(), pn.end(), b);
    sub.insert(sub.begin(), begin, end);
}
```

Comment: Can you be specific where I'm confusing? I would love to fix the question. Thanks a lot for your solution - I was not aware of lower_bound and upper_bound.

Comment: First it's strange that you're mixing ints and doubles.  Then, it's not clear whether the ranges you're indicating are inclusive or exclusive.  (A good practice is asymmetric ranges.)  Given the answer's elegance if you modify the question, please do so in a way that keeps the answer correct :-)

Comment: I see your confusion, but pn is just a pointer to single int that is the sub array's length (please see the definition of the linear subarray). No worries, your solution is quite elegant. I am using it now with success.

Answer (score 0):

You already appear to know that a binary search can be used to find the range, and implementations of those are easily found.

Everything else is just getting trivial array manipulation.

Comment: The binary search algos I know search for values - I'm having a bear of a time when searching using predicates. Hence, the plea for help.

Comment: true, you can't use the "bsearch" library function directly because that looks for exact matches, not >= or <=.  I'll investigate further...

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution:

- use binary search to find the lowest a and the highest b
- allocate a new array
- copy the values

Code is trivial as said before.